# Trigger update during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am animating a div (id="ani") using the following CSS code.

```
#ani {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        color:white;
        position :relative;
        animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    }
 @keyframes mymove {
    0%   {left: 0px;}
    25%  {left: 250px;}
    50%   {left:500px;}
    75%  {left: 250px}
    100% {left: 0px;}
}
```

I would like a know if there is a way to display the instantaneous value of the CSS 'left' property as it is changing i.e. the value of 'left' should be displayed all the time on the screen. Is there a way to bind 'left' value to say
any text field ? AngularJS seems to not work in style-sheets.

Comment: You can create an interval in javascript and check for the styles.left property on the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/scds974a/2/)**

```
$(function(){
    var div = $('#ani'),
        showLeft = $('#left');  

    setInterval(function () {
       showLeft.text(div.position().left)
     }, 10);
});
```